# Count of rendered polygons with tessellation

Tags: c++, opengl, polygon, opengl-4, tessellation

I want to know if there is a way to get the number of effective polygons (or vertices) rendered to a window when Hardware Tessellation is on. Due to adaptive tessellation, the polygon number changes from one frame to the next.

I'm using OpenGL 4.2 and render the mesh calling glDrawElements. I'm using full program shaders (Vertex, Tessellation Control, Tessellation Evaluation, Geometry and Fragment).

I have the initial number of polygons in an array, but after the tessellation stage is executed, this number is no longer valid.

I tried to use glGetQuery(GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED) but it always returns 0.

```
glGenQueries(1, query).
glBeginQuery(GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED, query).
//Draw stuff
glEndQuery(GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED).
glGetQueryObjectuiv(query, GL_QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE, &value).
```

Comment: That is definitely not going to do anything meaningful. If you want to get the result of a primitive query, you need to use `glGetQueryObjectuiv (<primitive query ID>, GL_QUERY_RESULT, &value)`. Moreover, you should wait until `GL_QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE` is **true** before doing this, or you will cause a pipeline stall. Can you show the code where you actually setup your primitive query? If you have not done so, I can give you some pseudo-code to properly set one up.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Sorry for the delay, I'm having problems with the Internet service. Here's what I do (after reading your comment) : glGenQueries(1, query). Then : glBeginQuery(GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED, query). Next comes the call to glBindBuffer and glDrawElements. Right after: glEndQuery(GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED). glGetQueryObjectuiv(query, GL_QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE, value). Value is always zero and the call to glGetQueryObjectuiv(query, GL_QUERY_RESULT, value) also returns 0.

Comment: This is C++, right? You should be using `&value`. It is not the return value that you are interested in, and you need to pass OpenGL the *address* of the `value` variable. I can only imagine right now that the compiler is allowing this because it is implicitly converting your integer to a pointer, but most compilers will at least warn you for trying to do that. Could you edit your original question and put the stuff you just mentioned into a code block? That would make understanding this a lot easier.

Comment: Indeed I am using &value but I wrote it wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The number of primitives generated is the same per vertex for a given LOD.  If you want to calculate the # triangles generated for each tessellation, you can do the calculations yourself, there's a set of equations over at:

[GLSL Tessellation shader number of triangles/faces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915705/glsl-tessellation-shader-number-of-triangles-faces/50285123#50285123)