# Formula for inner and outer tessellation factors given number of triangles

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, math, geometry, shader

I am trying to use tessellation to make all triangles on a mesh with varying sizes of triangles to be roughly the same size. I am doing this in unity. For simplicity we can assume that both inner and outer tessellation factors are the same.

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915705/glsl-tessellation-shader-number-of-triangles-faces) someone gave this recursive alorithm as an example of how to calculate the number of triangles that will result from any tessellation factor.

```
int calculateTriangles(int n) {    
    if(n < 0)   return 1;    
    if(n == 0)  return 0;
    return ((2*n -2) *3) + calculateTriangles(n-2);   
}
```

So one solution could be to reverse that recursion and use the area of each triangle as the desired number of triangles. But this is to be used in a shader and would therefore much rather have a formula that directly gives the tessellation factor, even if it is an approximation.

The closest I have gotten so far is log2(area + 1) but no dice it seems. I have also tried smaller and bigger logarithms but they all start behaving badly when the triangles are very small or very big.

Comment: "*I am trying to use tessellation to make all triangles on a mesh with varying sizes of triangles to be roughly the same size.*" How does tessellation help accomplish that goal? Shared edges *must* use the same tessellation level, or you [violate OpenGL's rules for maintaining continuity between adjacent triangles](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation#Patch_interface_and_continuity). That is, you'll see cracks between triangles.

Comment: @NicolBolas cracks does not matter, I only use the centerpoints of the generated triangles in the geometry shader

Comment: How about just using distance between center of triangle and camera. More the distance less will be tessellation levels. This is kind of function used in imolementing lod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calculateTriangles` function gives sequence that is **sum of arithmetic progression**, so `calculateTriangles(n)`value is about `3/2 * n^2`

Seems you need some kind of reverse function `A*Sqrt(x)`

Comment: This seems to be the corrrect way to do it. I still had some problems but I just realized that Unity has a cap of 64 on the tesselation factors. So triangles that were too big hit that limit and made it seem like the function was incorrect. Thank you for yor help!